# How to update AWS Cloudwatch Canary zip file

Tags: python, amazon-cloudwatch

I created a an AWS Cloudwatch Canary through the Import from S3 option, because I had a packaged python script and directory.  That went well, and works as expected.  However, I cannot find how to update the script package for the existing Canary.
There has to be an easier way than creating a new canary every time I update the zip, any thoughts?

If I upload a new zip to s3, it does not automatically read it in again, it continues to run the old code.  If I go to edit, there is no Upload option, just the parsed out handler function.  And, if I make any changes to the handler function it times out when saving it ("Error: Request Too Long").

Answer (score 1):

I still don't see a way to do this in the UI, but I am able to do it from the command line.  I now package up my scripts (zip), then update the zip in s3 (`aws s3 cp s3://path/python.zip`) and then
`aws synthetics update-canary --name test-canary --code '{"S3Bucket": "path", "S3Key":"python.zip", "Handler": "test-canary.handler"}'`